# Nuxt JS Mqtt client without websocket

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, mqtt

I'm trying to connect my VueJs application with a MQTT JS library (https://github.com/mqttjs) to a MQTT broker which doesn't support websocket.

For this motivation, I need a NodeJs server beetween Vue and the Broker which can handle the connection to the broker directly, without a websocket.

I believe that Nuxt JS could be the solution because it's basically VueJs integrated with a NodeJS server....

If I understood well, I can use the plugin feature of Nuxt to create a connection with the broker in this way:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import mqtt from 'mqtt';

const client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://broker.hivemq.com')

client.on('connect', function () {

  console.log("CONNECTED!");

  client.subscribe("mytopic", function(err){
    if(err)
      console.error("Error on topic subscribe: ", err);
    else
      console.info("Correctly subscribed to topic");
  });

})

Vue.prototype.$clientMqtt = client;
```

And then i can use the fetch hook on a Vue component in this way to listen for topic changes:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      mqttData:{
        topic: undefined,
        message: undefined
      }
    }
  },
  async fetch() {

    let vm = this;

    this.$clientMqtt.on('message', function (topic, message) {

      vm.mqttData.topic = topic;
      vm.mqttData.message = message.toString();

    });

  }
}
```

But the "mqttData" object that I show on my Vue template never updates...

Comment: Another option is to just implement a WS/MQTT bridge (it's the same wire protocol just bootstrapped over WS) to add WS support to the broker, e.g. https://github.com/dvdbng/mqtt-ws